# Heroku application error when deploying + using CLI clients

Tags: node.js, heroku, client, command-line-interface

I am working on a project in which I have to have a Node.js CLI client communicating with a Heroku server.

I tried to deploy a simple chat app example to make sure everything is working and was met with a Heroku error saying "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail"

Here are my Heroku logs when I run the above command, I am pretty sure the error has something to do with the server not being able to load the `socket-io` module when it deploys:

```
2021-04-26T00:05:05.310536+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-26T00:05:05.310536+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-26T00_05_05_288Z-debug.log
2021-04-26T00:05:05.386444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-26T00:05:05.490453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-26T00:05:05.494874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-26T00:05:08.142848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-26T00:05:11.291774+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.291802+00:00 app[web.1]: > test@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-26T00:05:11.291802+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-04-26T00:05:11.291802+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374875+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374878+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374879+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374879+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374880+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374880+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374880+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374881+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374881+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374882+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374882+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374882+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:12)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374883+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374883+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374883+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374887+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374888+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374888+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374889+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2021-04-26T00:05:11.374889+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-04-26T00:05:11.407116+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-26T00:05:11.407516+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-26T00:05:11.416214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2021-04-26T00:05:11.416464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-26T00:05:11.416760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-26T00:05:11.416976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-26T00:05:11.417532+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-26T00:05:11.430755+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.431385+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-26T00:05:11.431600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-26T00_05_11_418Z-debug.log
2021-04-26T00:05:11.505552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-26T00:05:11.580749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-26T00:05:13.627279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=41d7f800-0833-45ac-9a24-e9e984981929 fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-26T00:05:13.811879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=de243ea9-c7e1-4a74-91bd-4da78834b085 fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-26T00:13:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hbagalkote@gmail.com
2021-04-26T00:13:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-26T00:13:23.403605+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 12d7e839 by user hbagalkote@gmail.com
2021-04-26T00:13:23.403605+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user hbagalkote@gmail.com
2021-04-26T00:13:23.552491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-26T00:13:26.818012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914344+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914388+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914388+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914389+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914389+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914390+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914390+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914391+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914391+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914391+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914392+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:12)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914394+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914394+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914394+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2021-04-26T00:13:29.914395+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-04-26T00:13:29.974925+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-26T00:13:30.067473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-26T00:13:32.450999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=37d17d3f-c2b0-4bca-b1ca-36eb952e09de fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-26T00:13:32.618072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=13ff0bcf-2201-46d9-84ac-d05c91bd12ef fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-26T00:16:34.224143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-26T00:16:36.722190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725268+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725295+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725296+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725296+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725296+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725296+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725297+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725297+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725297+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725298+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725298+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725298+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:12)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725298+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725300+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725300+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725300+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2021-04-26T00:16:38.725301+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-04-26T00:16:38.775108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-26T00:16:38.832146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-26T00:17:40.388694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=f42d0aaf-a1db-4f6a-8888-063084139ca2 fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-26T00:17:40.499806+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=slingshot-test-nodejs.herokuapp.com request_id=34f18224-8dfd-40aa-93db-78ad61880e63 fwd="24.196.239.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Additionally, I have `web: node index.js` in my Procfile.

I am not quite sure why this is happening, as I have `socket-io` installed locally and the server and client worked properly when tested locally.

My second question is regarding the client and server code. Since I can hardcode port values when testing locally, the client and server communicate. However, how would I get the client to talk to the `index.js` code running in Heroku (assuming I get my first issue fixed)?

My client (client.js) and server (index.js) code are included below:

```js
//server code

const http = require('http').createServer()
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

http.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port: ' + port))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected')
    socket.on('message', (evt) => {
        console.log(evt)
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', evt)
    })
})
```

```js
//client code

//Obviously, this localhost value will not work, but what should I change it to instead?
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000')
const repl = require('repl')
const chalk = require('chalk')
var username = null

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socket.emit('disconnect')
})

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(chalk.red('== start chatting =='))
    username = process.argv[2]
})

socket.on('message', (data) => {
    const { cmd, username } = data
    console.log(chalk.green(username + ': ' + cmd.split("\n")[0]))
})

repl.start({
    prompt: '',
    eval: (cmd) => {
        socket.send({cmd, username})
    }
})
```

Comment: is `npm install` being run at any point during your deployment process?

Comment: No, but I changed the procfile starting command to ```npm start``` instead, and now I'm getting a ```Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch``` error.